# How to receive and send data from server to a client in loop

Tags: c, sockets

How to keep the connection listening from the connected client? In the below code the thread receives the data and replies to the client and disconnects. I want to put the receive and sent process in loop. How can I do that ?

```
void *thread_handle_connection(void *arg) {
  char buffer[MAX_MSG_SIZE]; // Receive buffer
  int bytes_read;

  do {

    // If there aren't any connections, sleep and recheck every second
    while(!num_connections && !term_requested) {
      sleep(1);
    }

    // Lock out connections queue and grab the first one
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_mutex);
    int connectionfd = remove_connection_from_queue();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);

    if(-1 == connectionfd) {
      continue;
    }

    // pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier); // Barrier for threads - for testing only

    // Read up to 1024 bytes from the client
    bytes_read = recv(connectionfd, buffer, MAX_MSG_SIZE - 1, 0);

    // If the data was read successfully
    if(bytes_read > 0) {
      // Add a terminating NULL character and print the message received
      buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';

      // Calculate response
      int multiplicand = atoi(buffer);
      char *response;
      asprintf(&response, "%d", multiplicand * MULTIPLIER);

      // Echo the data back to the client; exit loop if we're unable to send
      if(-1 == send(connectionfd, response, strlen(response), 0)) {
        warn("Unable to send data to client");
        break;
      }
      free(response);
    }

    // Close connection
    close(connectionfd);

  } while(bytes_read > 0 && !term_requested);

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: Well to wrap the receiving code in an actual loop would be a good start. Then just read and write in that loop until there is an error or the connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

First, `recv` function doesn't guarantee that you read everything that has been written by sender. You may get part of the data (for example sender may send 10KByte but receiver may receive only 1.5K on first read).

Second, `send` function doesn't guarantee that it send everything you ask. If not everything has been sent you need to send rest of the answer.

Third, TCP is stream oriented. This means that you need to separate one message from another. For text-based protocol typically "new line" is used for this purpose.

Putting all together. If you want persistent connection with request you need:

- define request and response separators
- maintain read buffer
- read all data to the buffer and scan it for request separator
- send response with response separator

If you want level up in networking programming you may want to know something about non-blocking operations and poll/select functions.